# Scope provided not working with mysql-connector-java maven war

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, pom.xml, mysql-connector

I've been trying to find a solution for this for a long time without success.
I have analyzed the dependence tree and seems to have no other lib requiring mysql-connector-java. Besides that, even with scope provided, the jar is being packed on the final war.

My dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.45</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And here my dependency hierarchy:

[image: dependency hierarchy]

Without this, my tomcat server keep giving memory leak errors on redeploy and I don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

Edit 1: full pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Server</groupId>
<artifactId>Server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Server</name>
<dependencies>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.45</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- other dependencies -->


</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Edit 2:

Dependency Hierarchy filtered with 'mysql'

[image]

Comment: First images are not a good idea...Apart from that have you checked the resulting WAR file? how does the full pom file look like?

Comment: Have you build your war with "clean package" and looked into the resulting war?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, I have checked my war, the file from mysqlconnector is inside it, apart from the provided scope on the pom file.
How do I build with clean package? Just clean the project?

Comment: Can't say from the image if mysql client jar is being packaged as a transitive dependency or not. Could you search for the string 'mysql' in your dependency hierarchy tab and update the image?

Comment: Hi Sashi, just did!